# Is there a jQuery method identical to hover except uses mouse clicks instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Is there a method that is identical to hover except instead of a mouse hover it uses a mouse click? the use would be for a vertical menu with sub menus. hover makes the menu too jerky and unstable. the html and psuedo js code are below, it shows what i'm trying to accomplish.

```
<ul id="global-left-nav">
<li><span class="menu-header">Synthesizers</span>
    <ul class="sub-cat">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><span class="menu-header">Drum Machines</span>
<ul class="sub-cat">
    <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li></ul>

$('.sub-cat').hide();

$('.menu-header').myTwoClickFunc(
//if clicked once
    function() {
    $(this).next('ul').slideDown();
    $(this).next('ul').addClass('open');
    $('ul.open').addClass('close');
 },
//if clicked twice
    function() {
    $(this).next('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).next('ul').addClass('close');
    });
```

i thought toggle might work but it doesn't alternate between 2 callback funcs. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('element').on('hover', function() { $(this).click() });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just toggle a class and use an if statement in your click handler:

```
$('.menu-header').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('open')) {
    // close it
  }
  else
  {
    // open it
  }

  $this.toggleClass('open')

})
```

Can you provide an example of the hover so that we can see what you mean by 'too jerky and unstable'.  Regardless if the action happens on `click` or `hover` what runs the animation is the same - it's just a different event that triggers it.

Comment: great, thanks. though i'm not familiar w/ toggleClass. will look that up.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.clickToggle = function (func1, func2) {
        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function () {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

$('.menu-header').clickToggle(

function () {
    $(this).next('ul').slideDown();
    $(this).next('ul').addClass('open');
    $('ul.open').addClass('close');
},

function () {
    $(this).next('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).next('ul').addClass('close');
});
```

or

use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
function second() {
    $(this).next('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).next('ul').addClass('close');
    $('.menu-header').one('click',first);
}

function first() {
    $(this).next('ul').slideDown();
    $(this).next('ul').addClass('open');
    $('ul.open').addClass('close');
    $('.menu-header').one('click',second);
}
$('.menu-header').one('click',first);
```